# Print to default printer in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing

How can I print html file directly to default printer in IE11 without asked what is my printer?

Please note this, I searched a lot how to do that, but I got none results.

Comment: My best advice would be to not use IE at all. Rather suggest that users use Chrome or something

Comment: I need to use IE because of styles that unique to this browser